# Is there a way to force a key release when using key binding?

Tags: java, key

Is there a way to release a key without actually releasing the key. I know this sounds weird but im trying to force my keys to always go back to released state no matter what. When my game loops right after a player loses it keeps the arrow key that was pressed continuously pressed even in the new game. when a new game is played the key needs to be pressed and released to deactivate the the key press.Any ideas?

```
 this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "Pright");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Pleft");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "Pup");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "Pdown");

        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0,true), "Rright");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0,true), "Rleft");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0,true), "Rup");
        this.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0,true), "Rdown");

        this.getActionMap().put("Pright", new ArrowAction("Pright"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Pleft", new ArrowAction("Pleft"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Pup", new ArrowAction("Pup"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Pdown", new ArrowAction("Pdown"));

        this.getActionMap().put("Rright", new ArrowAction("Rright"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Rleft", new ArrowAction("Rleft"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Rup", new ArrowAction("Rup"));
        this.getActionMap().put("Rdown", new ArrowAction("Rdown"));
```

Answer (score 0):

One one way of doing this would be by instead of using a action may and key binding, use a key listener. Then inside the key listener put a released boolean, that will check if the key has been pressed again after it has already been pressed to stop the event. This also means you can set it to released as you would just set the boolean to true.

Comment: Key Listeners have many issues regarding focus. In addition keyListener has a lower level functionality that make things complicated and unreliable.

Comment: I agree that they make things more complicated but I disagree that they are unreliable.

Comment: The unreliability comes from the focus. In fact keyBindings are easier to implement however they complicate things when using Jcomponents. Key bindings do not require the programmer to worry about focus.